# How to assign all variables (at the same time) genereted in a function into the global environmental?

Tags: r

This is what I want to obtain, but avoiding to add "e$" before all my variables inside the function. Thanks

```
e <- globalenv()
f <- function(P) {
  e$c <- P + 1
  e$d <- c + 2

}

f(2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a **very** bad idea, but you *can* do

```
f <- function(P) {
  x <<- P + 1
  y <<- x + 2

}

f(2)
```

I am not using variable `c` because that is also a (rather important) function name. And it would fail, indeed.

If you need to pass the multiple values returned by the first function (`f1`) to another function (`f2`), what you should do is something like:

```
f1 <- function(P) {
  x <- P + 1
  y <- x + 2
  list(x=x, y=y)  
}

f2 <- function(x, y) {
   x + y
}

r <- f1(2)
f2(r$x, r$y)
```

or

```
r <- f1(2)
do.call(f2, r)
```

Comment: Thanks RobertH, I know this, but there are other solutions?

Comment: Your script works with x and y as name of the variables, but when the names are c and d I have an error: Error in f(2) : cannot change value of locked binding for 'c'. I don't understand why.

Comment: Sorry RobertH, I have little confidence with R, but Why is a bad idea? Which could be the best strategy to return more of one variable from a single function?

Comment: It is a bad idea because it overwrites any existing symbol with the same name in the global environment. The normal practice is to return a list `f = function(P) { x = P + 1; list(x = x, y = x + 2) }` and to work with the list `ans = f(3); ans$x`.

Comment: Sorry Martin, but for my scope I need to recall several variables created inside the functions in the global environmental (in the subsequent functions). How can I do?

Comment: I have added examples of how you should to this.